# sum aggerate in sql query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How can i sum or add (PDetail.DETAIL_FOR_QTY) on the current query?

```
SELECT        PDetail.PLU, PDetail.DETAIL_FOR_QTY, PLU.PLU_DESC, PLU.LAST_PRICE
FROM            PDetail INNER JOIN
                     PLU ON PDetail.PLU = PLU.PLU_NUM
WHERE        (PDetail.DEPT = 26) AND (PDetail.StoreNumber IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16))    AND (PDetail.TIME_STAMP BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                     '2013-06-20 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-06-20 23:59:59', 102))
ORDER BY PLU.PLU_DESC
```

Currently, I get something like this:

```
08024401    1   item1   17.4900
08048003    1   item2   22.9900
08048004    1   item3   22.9900
08048004    1   item3   22.9900
```

I'm trying to add up these two since they are the same (based on PDetail INNER JOIN PLU ON PDetail.PLU = PLU.PLU_NUM):

```
PDetail.PLU    PDetail.DETAIL_FOR_QTY      PLU.PLU_DESC            Don't need to add this
08048004        1                                 item3                       22.9900
08048004        1                                 item3                       22.9900
```

Desired Results:

```
08024401    1   item1   17.4900
08048003    1   item2   22.9900
08048004    2   item3   22.9900
```

Comment: Can you please post your desired results?

Comment: Please add it to your answer so that it is formatted.

Comment: So, if Item3 where in your raw result set twice with 2 different Last Prices, would you want two rows, or the max of the two prices?

Comment: no, i just want to add the PDetail.DETAIL_FOR_QTY  column.  the price is not relevant.

Comment: If it's not relevant, why are you returning it in your result set?  If you are returning it in your result set, you need to explain how you want it aggregated.

Comment: it relevant in the query, but not relevant in the question.  basically, item1 has a sku, item2 etc.  4 items sold.  1 of items1, 1 of item2 and 2 of item3.  the query separates the sales.  i want to add like items together for a total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this did the trick:

```
SELECT        PDetail.PLU, SUM(PDetail.DETAIL_FOR_QTY) AS DETAIL_FOR_QTY, PLU.PLU_DESC,       PLU.LAST_PRICE
FROM            PDetail INNER JOIN
                     PLU ON PDetail.PLU = PLU.PLU_NUM
WHERE        (PDetail.DEPT = 26) AND (PDetail.StoreNumber IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16)) AND (PDetail.TIME_STAMP BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                     '2013-06-20 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-06-20 23:59:59', 102))
GROUP BY PDetail.PLU, PLU.PLU_DESC, PLU.LAST_PRICE, PDetail.DETAIL_FOR_QTY
ORDER BY PLU.PLU_DESC, PDetail.PLU
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments to the questions, you simply want

```
select PDetail.PLU, 
       sum(DETAIL_FOR_QTRY) as [QUANTITY SUM],
       PLU.PLU_Description,
       MAX(PLU.Last_Price)
FROM   PDetail 
INNER JOIN PLU 
ON PDetail.PLU = PLU.PLU_NUM
WHERE    (PDetail.DEPT = 26) 
AND      (PDetail.StoreNumber IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16))
AND      (PDetail.TIME_STAMP BETWEEN 
                                CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-06-20 00:00:00', 102) 
                            AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-06-20 23:59:59', 102))
GROUP BY PDetail.PLU, PLU.PLU_Description
```

Comment: What's the error?  Oh wait, I put "LAST_PRICE" on the wrong table.  Try it now.

Comment: SQL Execution ERROR. The {statement} cannot call methods on varchar.

Comment: Understood.  But there must be an error message coming back from SQL Server.  Can you just try to run the SQL in Management Studio and debug it there, before embedding it in your application?

Comment: yes, found some other syntax errors.  working through those also.

Comment: Awesome.  Can you accept it so that this question becomes "Answered"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. sum(PDetail.DETAIL_FOR_QTY). Then use Group By for non-unique columns.

Comment: In your select statement simply add the column you want to sum in the aggregate function sum(). Then at the very end add Group By clause for the rest of the columns you used.